# Symfony 4 Entities generator bad path problem

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony4

I'm trying to Entities based on metada but generator always create objects in bad path. Instead of creating objects in the following paths:

- src/Entities

It creates them in:

- src/App/Entities

Comment: paste the command that you are using

Comment: First, I execute the command

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" xml --path=config/doctrine

and then

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/Entity

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is added from the beginning